# PeoplePicker fields in SharePoint Modal dialog, loses data with SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, refresh, sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

I've got an issue with the SharePoint PeoplePicker control. When a Modal dialog is open and in Edit mode, it's possible to use the builtin function SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) to refresh the page without losing changes in data. Fields like Text, Note, Choice, Date etc. works fine and their changes are not lost when SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK). 
But PeoplePicker fields unfortunately loses their data!

Steps to reproduce

1. Create simple item with a user field
2. Make item open in dialog (List Settings - Advanced - Launch forms in dialog)
3. Create an item
4. Open the EditForm of the item
5. Update the people picker field
6. Execute SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) in a console

Answer (score 0):

Made a fix by storing PeoplePicker values in sessionStorage upon RefreshPage() and reload them afterwards.

TypeScript 1.8

```
// FIX for SPClientPeoplePicker not preserving state afre SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage...
export class ClientPeoplePickerFix {
    static getPplPickerElementsInForm = (): Array<HTMLInputElement> => {
        var result = new Array<HTMLInputElement>();
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].elements;

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var currentEl = (<HTMLInputElement>elements[i]);

            if (currentEl.name.indexOf("$ClientPeoplePicker_HiddenInput") > -1) {
                result.push(currentEl);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    static storePeoplePickerValues = (): void => {
        var elements = ClientPeoplePickerFix.getPplPickerElementsInForm();

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var currentEl = elements[i];

            var pplPicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(currentEl);
            var currentUserInfo = pplPicker.GetAllUserInfo();

            if (currentUserInfo.length > 0) {
                sessionStorage.setItem(currentEl.name, JSON.stringify(currentUserInfo));
            }
        }
    }

    static restorePeoplePickerValues = (): void => {
        var elements = ClientPeoplePickerFix.getPplPickerElementsInForm();

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var currentEl = elements[i];

            var currentUserInfoSerialized = sessionStorage.getItem(currentEl.name);

            if (currentUserInfoSerialized) {
                var pplPicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(currentEl);
                var currentUserInfo = JSON.parse(currentUserInfoSerialized);

                currentUserInfo.forEach((user) => {
                    pplPicker.AddProcessedUser(user, true);
                });

                sessionStorage.removeItem(currentEl.name);
            }
        }
    }

    static overrideRefreshPage = (): void => {
        var _refreshPage = SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage;

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage = function () {
            if (arguments && arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
                ClientPeoplePickerFix.storePeoplePickerValues();
            }

            _refreshPage.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}


// Override SP.UI.Modal.Dialog.RefreshPage
// Store values from all SPClientPeoplePickers in sessionStorage when SP.UI.Modal.Dialog.RefreshPage is called
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(() => {
    ClientPeoplePickerFix.overrideRefreshPage();
}, "sp.ui.dialog.js");

// On page load
// Restore SPClientPeoplePicker values from sessionStorage and add in appropriate controls
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(() => {
    ClientPeoplePickerFix.restorePeoplePickerValues();
}, "sp.core.js");
```